# spring boot does not read the correct property file

Tags: spring-boot

```
[root@xx ~]# tree /data/portal/
/data/portal/
├── portal.jar
└── config
    └── application.properties   // I wish it read this
```

`java -jar portal.jar` does not read properties in config folder, it stubbornly reads the same file in jar package. However, based on [24.3 Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) jar should read the configuration in config folder. Maven project too. Now I have to manually configure the file location by `--spring.config.location`.

EDIT:
I have just found that, by using `--spring.config.location=file:/absolutepath/config/application.yml` does not actually load any included property files. like this:

```
spring.profiles.include: 'routes'
```

does not load application-routes.yml, even though log says `The following profiles are active: routes`

Comment: Did you run this from the /data/portal directory? It seems like the application does not run with current directory set to /data/portal, so the file does not get picked up. You can try to log out `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see whether the app is running from the correct directory.

Comment: @thomi I tried both, run in `/data/portal`, or run from a random folder in which there is a `config/application.properties`. It was working before, but after we reboot the app it could not read the correct one.